# MATLAB - How to merge figure sections vertically

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to display three figures in a figure window.

Assuming that I divide 2x2 regions.

```
subplot(2,2,1)



---------+-----------
| R1     |    R2    |
---------+-----------
| R3     |    R4    |
---------+-----------
```

I want to show a figure merging R1 and R3 ant other two in R2 and R4

I can display them merging R1-R2 or merging R3-R4

```
subplot(2,2,1:2)
subplot(2,2,3:4)
```

but, cannot merge them vertically.

Comment: Try: `subplot(1,2,1); subplot(2,2,2); subplot(2,2,4);`

Comment: Did that work fully?

Comment: @BenVoigt yes. You may write it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite simple; just feed into `subplot` the locations as a vector.

For instance,

```
x = -2*pi:0.01:2*pi;
subplot(2,2,[1,3])
plot(x,sin(x))
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(x,cos(x))
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(x,x.^2)
```

gives:
[image]